# AngularJS Directive to modify URL

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

In my templates i am able to display an image from my data using

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{f.flower.imageURL}})'}"
```

The imageURL always returns a hi-res image with URL such as

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/FlowerImages/Rose_1920.jpg
```

However the endpoint also has smaller images such as

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/FlowerImages/Rose_320.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/FlowerImages/Rose_480.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/FlowerImages/Rose_1024.jpg
```

How would i create a directive to traverse back through the URL up to the underscore and pass in a size i want (depending on the view) to update between the underscore and the .jpg?

Comment: numerous ways to do this in conjunction with your `{{}}` expression... controller function or  custom filter are two that come to mind. `{{getImage(f.flower.imageURL)}}` for example. Then use another variable to toggle size condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you example, I don't think you need a directive.  Just add a function to your controller.

Instead of

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{f.flower.imageURL}})'}"
```

do

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{generateImageUrl(f.flower.imageURL, 320)}})'}"
```

And your controller would have standard javascript to manipulate the url:

```
function generateImageUrl(url, size) {
  var n = url.lastIndexOf("_");
  var beforeUnderscore = url.substring(0, n);
  var afterUnderscore = url.substring(n+1);
  var suffix = afterUnderscore.split('.')[1];

  return beforeUnderscore + "_" + size + "." + suffix;
}
```

The same function could work for image as well

```
<img ng-src="{{generateImageUrl(f.flower.imageURL, 320)}}">
```

Note: `ng-src` is used instead of `src` to prevent the browser from requested the url before angular has bootstrapped.